# AWS replication agent installation issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication

Trying to install AWS replication agent on EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2 after download ths setup init file  using this command

```
chmod +x aws-replication-installer-init; sudo ./aws-replication-installer-init
```

i got this error : cannot execute binary file.

Kernel version 5.10.135-122.509.amzn2.aarch64

Please Help! , i don't find any solution.

i installed all required package :

```
sudo yum install elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Python installed on the source server (version 2.4+, version 3.0+)

> file aws-replication-installer-init :

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
```

> uname -mpio

```
aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```